# Safe encryption algorithm that works with files bigger than 68GB

Tags: aes, file-encryption, algorithm

In my Java application, I used AES/GCM/NoPadding algorithm for encryption, however it throws an exception when I try to encrypt files bigger than ~68GB. From what I read, it is limit of data that can be encrypted using GCM.

I know that there is a possibility to split bigger files and then merge them, but this seems like a complicated solution. Is there an algorithm that is as safe as GCM, but handles massive files?

I tested CBC, and this works with bigger files, however I read that it is ~40yo, and not as safe, due to lack of authorization. Does it really cause safety problems? Are there any alternatives?

**Edit:**
Thank you all. As a result of Sonar marking CBC as unsafe and orders from senior architect, I implemented file split/merge with GCM in application.

Comment: this might be helpful : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35520/should-i-use-xts-or-gcm-to-encrypt-my-hard-drives

Comment: I wonder how do you generate encryption keys for the individual split blocks.     An "encrypt then MAC" construct can add integrity protection to any mode including  CBC, but it has a disadvantage of iterating over the data twice, while AES-GCM does it in a single pass.

Comment: I'm using the same key for all parts of file.

Answer (score 2):

GCM mode combines CTR (counter) mode with [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) called [GHASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Mathematical_basis). You can use virtually any standard block mode if you combine a MAC with it. For example, you can use AES in CBC or CTR mode if you also use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), a MAC that uses cryptographic hashes for authentication. It is always better to encrypt first and then apply the HMAC over the ciphertext, a construction called [Encrypt-then-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Encrypt-then-MAC_(EtM)) (EtM).

Comment: Please [see](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31793/18298)

Comment: The other comment by @kelalaka nicely explains the AES-GCM limit, but it is almost invisible because the size of it and it is too easy to miss [the included link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31793/18298)